# Quiz game difficulty level using one column in SQLite Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am creating a quiz game on android studio which has three different difficulty levels easy, medium and hard.  Last time I asked, I was suggested I should use a column which represents difficulty and use that to call the difficult. (the question can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315274/android-studio-quiz-game-sqlite-database-multiple-tables-for-different-game-diff).

1) I have used the method which was suggested, however when I select easy, medium or hard it loads up the same questions for each difficult.

2) the game should show four multiple answer however the top answer is blank but when I click on the blank answer the game ends (see the picture attached)

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCnO2.png)

```
package com.example.sqz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;



public class level extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level);
}


public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    Intent a = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class); a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(a);
}

public void btnEasy(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
public void btnMedium(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btnHard(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

> Blockquote

```
package com.example.sqz;




import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQZ";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTN1 = "OPTN1"; // option 1
private static final String KEY_OPTN2 = "OPTN2"; // option 2
private static final String KEY_OPTN3 = "OPTN3"; // option 3
private static final String KEY_OPTN4 = "OPTN4"; // option 4
private static final String DIFFICULT = "difficult";

private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

public QuizHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase = db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " +DIFFICULT+ " INTEGER, " + KEY_OPTN1 + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTN2 + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTN3 + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTN4 + "  TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    addQuestion();
    // db.close();
}

private void addQuestion() {
    Question q1 = new Question("Which team won FIFA world cup in 2002 ?",0, "Brazil", "England","Germany", "Italy", "Brazil");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2 = new Question("How many goals Messi scored UEFA Champions League 2015  ?",0, "7", "6", "5", "8", "6");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3 = new Question("Which team won cricket world cup in 2015  ?",0, "Australia", "England","New Zealand", "South Africa", "Australia");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4 = new Question("Which team won premier league in 2015  ?",1, "Arsenal", "Manchester city", "Liverpool", "Chelsea", "Chelsea");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5 = new Question("What team does LeBron James play for ?",1, "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Charlotte Hornets", "Los Angeles Clippers", "Miami Heat", "Cleveland Cavaliers");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6 = new Question("Who scored the most goals in 2013  ?",1, "Lionel Messi", "Zlatan Ibrahimovic", "thierry henry", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Cristiano Ronaldo");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7 = new Question("Which team won world twenty20 in 2012  ?",2, "Australia", "West Indies", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "West Indies");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8 = new Question("Who won Formula 1 championship in 2013  ?",2, "Fernando Alonso", "Sebastian Vettel", "Esteban Gutierrez", "Lewis Hamilton", "Sebastian Vettel");
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9 = new Question("Who won world darts championship in 2015 ?",2, "Gary Anderson", "Phil Taylor", "Boris Koltsov", "Michael van Gerwen", "Gary Anderson");
    this.addQuestion(q9);


    // END
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTN1, quest.getOPT1());
    values.put(KEY_OPTN2, quest.getOPT2());
    values.put(KEY_OPTN3, quest.getOPT3());
    values.put(KEY_OPTN4, quest.getOPT4());

    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}

public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTN1(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTN2(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setOPTN3(cursor.getString(5));
            quest.setOPTN4(cursor.getString(6));
            quest.setDIFFICULT(cursor.getString(7));

            questionList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    List<Question> shuffledQuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();



    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        shuffledQuestionList.add(questionList.get(list.get(i)));


    return shuffledQuestionList;

}


}
```

> Blockquote

```
package com.example.sqz;



import android.app.Activity;

public class Question extends Activity {

private int ID;
private String QUESTION;
private String OPTION1;
private String OPTION2;
private String OPTION3;
private String OPTION4;
private int DIFFICULT;

private String ANSWER;


public Question() {
    ID = 0;
    QUESTION = "";
    OPTION1 = "";
    OPTION2 = "";
    OPTION3 = "";
    OPTION4 = "";

    ANSWER = "";

}

public Question(String qUESTION,int DIFFCULTY, String OPTN1, String OPTN2, String OPTN3, String OPTN4,
                String aNSWER ) {
    QUESTION = qUESTION;
    OPTION1 = OPTN1;
    OPTION2 = OPTN2;
    OPTION3 = OPTN3;
    OPTION4 = OPTN4;
    DIFFICULT = DIFFCULTY;

    ANSWER = aNSWER;

}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getQUESTION() {
    return QUESTION;
}

public String getOPT1() {
    return OPTION1;
}

public String getOPT2() {return OPTION2;}

public String getOPT3() {return OPTION3;}

public String getOPT4() {return OPTION4;}

public int getDIFFICULT() {
    return DIFFICULT;
}

public String getANSWER() {
    return ANSWER;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    ID = id;
}

public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
    QUESTION = qUESTION;
}

public void setOPTN1(String OPTN1) {
    OPTION1 = OPTN1;
}

public void setOPTN2(String OPTN2) {OPTION2 = OPTN2;    }

public void setOPTN3(String OPTN3) {OPTION3 = OPTN3;}

public void setOPTN4(String OPTN4) {OPTION4 = OPTN4;}

public void setDIFFICULT(String DIFFICULT) {DIFFICULT = DIFFICULT;}

public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
    ANSWER = aNSWER;
}

}

}
```

> Blockquote

```
package com.example.sqz;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;


Question currentQuestion;
TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all quetonall questions
    currentQuestion = quesList.get(qid); // the current question

    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    // the textview in which the question will be displayed

    // the three buttons,
    // the idea is to set the text of three buttons with the options from question bank
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    // the textview in which score will be displayed
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    // the timer
    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);


    // method which will set the things up for our game
    setQuestionView();
    times.setText("00:0:00");

    // A timer of 60 seconds to play for, with an interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(200000, 1000);
    timer.start();

    // button click listeners
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // passing the button text to other method
            // to check whether the anser is correct or not
            // same for all three buttons
            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button4.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    if (currentQuestion.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {

        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view
        score++;
        scored.setText("Score : " + score);
    } else {

        // if unlucky start activity and finish the game

        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);

        // passing the int value
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    if (qid < 20) {

        // if questions are not over then do this
        currentQuestion = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    } else {

        // if over do this
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        times.setText(hms);
    }


}

private void setQuestionView() {

    // the method which will put all things together
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(currentQuestion.getOPT1());
    button2.setText(currentQuestion.getOPT2());
    button3.setText(currentQuestion.getOPT3());
    button4.setText(currentQuestion.getOPT4());

    qid++;
}


}
```

> Blockquote

```
package com.example.sqz;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, level.class);

    startActivity(intent);

}

public void Instructions(View view) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder Instructions = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Instructions.setMessage("The SQZ is designed to test your knowledge across variety of sports, to play: \n1. Click Play \n2. Select Dificulty \n3. when quiz begins, three answers will be provided select the correct one. ")
            .setPositiveButton("Got It", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("Instructions")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.queslogo1)
            .create();
    Instructions.show();
}

public void btnQuit(View view) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
            .setTitle("Closing Application")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Quit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}

public void btnOptions(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnOptions)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, options.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public void QuestionMark(MenuItem item) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder generalinfo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    generalinfo.setMessage("Important Note: \nAll the images used in this application are created by the developer.\nThe application has been tested on android version 4.4 and 5.1 ")
            .setPositiveButton("Got It", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("General Information")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.queslogo1)
            .create();
    generalinfo.show();
}

public void email(MenuItem item) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder contact = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    contact.setMessage("If you have any suggestions email them to me  at\nusman_saddique@hotmail.co.uk ")
            .setPositiveButton("Got It", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("Contact")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.emaillogo1)
            .create();
    contact.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Here you get **ALL** your questions. Regardless of the difficulty level. `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;` which is **useless**. You should add a where clause to get only the questions of a selected difficulty (which you would select via a Spinner, a RadioGroup or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code thoroughly, but as you perform exactly the same statements in the methods for btnEasy, btnMedium, and btnHard, the effect of pressing them must be the same.

You probably want to add the difficulty level as an extra to your intent, and in the receiving activity evaluate this to choose the appropriate questions. The proper place to select questions would be your DB helper class. The method to get questions might take the difficulty as a parameter and only return those questions that match the required difficulty.

Hint, not meant as an insult: Your code shows that you are neither well acquainted with Java nor with Android. Take your time to read introductory books about both, so you'll be in control of the code you're writing.